# RabbitMQ missing channel reference in message delivery_info

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, php-amqplib

I'm currently implementing some logic after getting message from rabbitMQ using basic_get without automatically sending ack for messages being received.

According to the tutorial [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html) (Message acknowledgment section), I can't find the channel reference within the msg itself and send ack like mentioned in above link:

```
$msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
```

That is because in my msg delivery info array there is no such thing channel.
I wonder how could it be that it is missing.

**Edit**: code snippet of basic get

```
  $msg = $this->channel->basic_get($this->queueName, false);
```

Here is a var_dump of my message:(Yellow part)
[image: ampq message]l

Comment: Please provide the snipped of your basic_get as well, are you setting autoAck parameter there?

Comment: @jylipaa: added see above

Comment: Well that seems to be fine. Could you also show the publishing part, both channel/queue declaration and publishing

Comment: `$msg = new AMQPMessage($data);
 $this->channel->basic_publish($msg,'',$this->queueName);`

Comment: @jylipaa: Any new ideas?

Comment: Nothing much so far - your publishing function call looks fine too. It might have something to do with the queue/exchange declaration, could you show that piece of code too?

Comment: Try to look into php-amqplib examples - https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/tree/master/demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the AMQP spec `get-ok` which is the return value of `basic-get` doesn't include the channel, in contrast to what happens with `basic-deliver`, which is used when a message arrives for a consumer started with `basic-consume`.

So the library behaviour is correct.

See https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php#L1022

vs

https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php#L956

Answer (score 0):

When using basic_get (which seems to be discouraged, use basic_consume instead), try acking the message directly from channel using delivery_tag

$this->channel->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);

Comment: Nothing much interesting about rabbitMQ declaration
 `$this->connection = new AMQPConnection($this->queueIP, $this->queuePort, $this->queueUsername, $this->queuePassword);`

Comment: What is the problem with Basic_get? And what's the difference between this and basic_consume?

Comment: Well, if your only target is to fetch just one message, then get works fine. But immediately when you either need to wait for messages or need to process more than one, there will be slowness.

And check the queue declaration, but to connection declaration. What you have in $this->channel->queue_declare() as params?

Comment: `$this->channel->queue_declare($this->queueName, false, false, false, false);`  Sorry for the late response, is the queue declaration okay?

Comment: Well, that does look fine too. I'm running out of ideas.

I'd suggest to take a look on basic_consume after all, there are some working examples: 
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html